How to Determine the Position of the Optical Center in Thick Asymmetric Lenses?
In the case of thin symmetric lenses, the optical center coincides with the geometric center, as the lens can be considered to have negligible thickness. However, for thicker and asymmetric lenses, the optical center may not necessarily lie at the geometric center and can be located at some point along the principal axis.
How do we determine the position of the optical center in such cases? Specifically, what is the method or formula to find the optical center for thick asymmetric lenses, taking into account their shape and thickness?

The word you are looking for is Cardinal point or principal point.

There is no single “plug-and-play” formula that instantly gives the optical center for any arbitrary, thick, asymmetric lens (especially if multiple surfaces are involved).Instead I am going to provide the method. Here below is the method to find the optical (nodal) center  of a thick or asymmetric lens:

Model each refracting surface and the lens thickness using ABCD (ray-transfer) matrices. Refraction at a spherical surface (from index $n_1$ to $n_2$, radius R):
$$
M_{\text{surf}} =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\[6pt]
\frac{n_{1} - n_{2}}{R\,n_{2}} & \frac{n_{1}}{n_{2}}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
And Translation (thickness) in refractive index n over distance t:
$$
M_{\text{trans}} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \frac{t}{n} \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Multiply these matrices in sequence to get the system matrix
$M$:
$$
M = M_{\text{surf}_2} \cdot M_{\text{trans}} \cdot M_{\text{surf}_1} =
\begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\
C & D
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Extract the cardinal points from $M$.Once you have the system matrix $M$ and you know the focal lengths (and thus the focal points), you can use the standard paraxial formulas to locate the principal planes. In a coaxial lens system in air, the nodal points (which serve as the “optical center”) coincide with the principal planes. Therefore, once you have located the two principal planes $H_1$ and $H_2$, you effectively know the positions of the nodal points $N_1$ and $N_2$.As we know The optical (nodal) center for a lens in air is the same as the principal plane location. Thus you have the optical center.

